# Firebase Hosting cleanUrls fails to work in production

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to use the `cleanUrls` option to drop `.html` in routes. Works nicely locally with `firebase serve`. But once deployed to prod, `.html` is required.

My test site: https://maptennis.firebaseapp.com/
Click on Login will drive you to `/login` and gives a 404. Append `.html` to the URL and it will work.

My firebase.json config file:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public"
  },
  "cleanUrls": true,
  "trailingSlash": false
}
```

Any insight here would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue. My firebase.json file looked like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public"
  },
  "cleanUrls": true
}
```

I noticed I was using an older version of Firebase CLI. When I updated to the latest version and tried to deploy with same config file, following error occurred:

> hosting: We found a hosting key inside firebase.json as well as
>   hosting configuration keys that are not nested inside the hosting key.
>
> Please run firebase tools:migrate to fix this issue. Please note that
>   this will overwrite any configuration keys nested inside the hosting
>   key with configuration keys at the root level of firebase.json.
>
> Error: Hosting key and legacy hosting keys are both present in
>   firebase.json.

I changed my json config file to this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "cleanUrls": true
  }
}
```

Deploy was successful and `cleanUrls` worked this time :)